# Return multiple responses in Java

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a java method, that reads from Table A (with BLOB), writes certain data to Table B and finally uploads the BLOB to a file-server. This is the code:

```
public void insertAndUploadService() throws Exception {

    List<Tiedosto> tiedostoList = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer newRow = 0;
    boolean uploaded;

    try {
        tiedostoList = tiedostoService.getAllFiles();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Tiedosto tiedosto : tiedostoList){
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setCustomerId(tiedosto.getCustomerId());
        attachment.setSize(tiedosto.getFileSize());

        try {
            newRow = attachmentService.createNew(attachment);
            System.out.println("************ NEW ROW CREATED IN attachments ******************************");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (newRow == 1 && tiedosto.getContent() != null){
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tiedosto.getContent());
            minioFileServer.uploadFile("test", attachment.getUuid(), tiedosto.getFileName().substring(tiedosto.getFileName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1), byteArrayInputStream,
                    byteArrayInputStream.available(), tiedostoService.getMimeType(tiedosto.getContent()));
            System.out.println("********************** Generating Upload Link ************************************ "+"\n"+
                    minioFileServer.getUploadLinkForFile("test", attachment.getUuid(), tiedosto.getFileName().substring(tiedosto.getFileName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1) ));
            uploaded = minioFileServer.fileExists("test", attachment.getUuid(), tiedosto.getFileName().substring(tiedosto.getFileName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

            if (uploaded == true){
                System.out.println("*********** UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL ***************");
                tiedostoService.updateService(tiedosto.getCustomerId(), tiedosto.getId());
                attachmentService.update(attachment.getUuid());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If I send POST request to an API endpoint, something like:

```
@POST
@Path("attachments")
public void moveToMinio() throws Exception {
    MigrationService migrationService = new MigrationService();
    migrationService.insertAndUploadService();
}
```

It does the work as required and prints out the details. Is it by any chance possible to send multiple responses from insertAndUploadService when POST request is sent? For example when newRow is created and uploaded == true, is it possible to return HTTP 202? I'm new to Java and would really appreciate any sort of help/suggestions!

EDIT:
"Multiple responses" wasn't probably the right term. I'd like the option to return one of several HTTP status codes, chosen based on the request actions.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in this context what does _"multiple responses"_ mean?

Comment: @lealceldeiro sorry if I failed to explain it clearly. The POST request writes a new row to another table and continues uploading the file. What I need is, to return HTTP 202 when a new row is created and the same when file is uploaded to the server.

Comment: If I understand correctly, instead of _multiple_ responses at once you're wanting the option to return one of several possible responses, chosen based on the request actions?

Comment: @chrylis, that's absolutely correct. Any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: No response can be only 1.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with JAX-RS to make any suggestions; I use Spring MVC for this sort of task. It may be helpful to know that the specific term for what you're wanting is to set the *HTTP status code*.

Comment: @chrylis, Exactly! When a new row is created and upload is handled, I'd like to set HTTP 202 to be returned.

Comment: Return a `Response`. Then you set whatever status code you want. If you return void, it will always be 204. `Response.status(202).build()`.

Comment: @user1803551 Thanks for the link. I kinda solved it somehow.